# searchTerms is empty in INSearchForPhotosIntentHandling

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I'm developing an app that searches for photos in my database using the `SiriKit` API.

So far, Siri recognizes my app and the command for searching photos, but, when the confirm and the handle (`INSearchForPhotosIntentHandling` delegate) methods are called, the searchTerms in the intent attribute is empty.

So, when I say "Search for dogs in PetFinder", the searchTerms should contain the word 'dogs' right?

Does anyone know why the searchTerms is empty? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try saying "search for photos with Dogs in PetFinder"